# Code transition glitches in an ideal DAC

Tags: dac, resolution, mixed-signal

I have read in most books and articles that a code-to-code glitch is caused by imperfect timing in the switching of bits into a DAC.

If that was true, then there should be no glitch when you use an ideal DAC and ideal voltage sources to switch bits at the same time.

For DACs,
$$V_{out} = k \sum_n b_n\,2^n \tag 1$$

Where k is a constant.

If you take derivatives:

$$\frac d {dt} V_{out} = k \sum_n \frac d {dt} b_n 2^n \tag 2$$

then for a major carry transition, say 011..111 to 100...000, then even if the bits switch at the same time at the same rate \$\frac {db}{dt}\$

$$\frac d {dt} V_{out} = k \left ( \frac {db}{dt} 2^n -\frac {db}{dt} 2^{n-1} - \cdots \frac {db}{dt} 2^0 \right) \tag 3$$

This will simplify to

$$\frac d {dt} V_{out} = k \left (\frac {db}{dt} 2^n - \frac {db}{dt} \left (2^n - 1 \right) \right)
= k\frac {db}{dt} = \frac d {dt} V_{bit} \tag 4$$

It looks like the output will just track with the MSB transition (0 to Vdd) until the transitions are done. Basically a glitch.

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have put your math into \$\LaTeX\$; you may wish to double-check my edits.

Comment: An ideal DAC takes no time i.e. db/dt is undefined at the transition. If you like, this can be represented as Dirac deltas (+/- infty at the instant), with integral-amplitude equal to the code change, but whatever the case, a definition must be made.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point of an idealized device, and this is leading you to overthink things.  Ideal bits are binary things; they only take on values of zero or one, and they switch instantaneously.

If you define your ideal DAC such that the bits all switch both instantaneously and simultaneously, then when you are, for example, going from 0111 to 1000, there is no moment where the DAC is acting on anything other than 0111 or 1000, so it will switch smoothly from \$\frac 7 {16}\$ of the reference voltage to \$\frac 1 2\$ of the reference voltage.

If you did want to think about the derivative of the bit values, then you could assign them as \$\delta(t - t_0)\$, where \$t_0\$ is the moment the DAC switches.  Then the derivative of the DAC value would be
$$\frac{d}{dt} V_{out} = 8 V_b \delta(t - t_0) - 4 V_b \delta(t - t_0) - 2 V_b \delta(t - t_0) - V_b \delta(t - t_0) \tag 1$$

The trick here is to *stay in cloud-coukoo land* -- don't say "but real impulses can't happen simultaneously" -- instead, say "ah, I have four identical impulses that I can simplify into one", and you get the expected derivative of a perfect one-LSB stair step:
$$\frac{d}{dt} V_{out} = V_b \delta(t - t_0) \left(8 - 4 - 2 - 1 \right) = V_b \delta(t - t_0) \tag 2$$

Comment: I did want to consider an ideal DAC with nonideal input voltage sources, nonzero rise time. But the voltage sources applied to the bit inputs should have exactly the same rise times/rate of change.  I am asking this because when I make an ideal r2r dac in simulation, there are glitches at every major carry transition even with perfectly timed signals. There are no stray capacitances or nonideal switches. Just resistors and voltage pulse generators